# how to get hard disk serial number with action script

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, hard-drive, serial-number

I'm using action script 3.0 compiling the code to flash 10

how to get hard disk serial number with action script?

I want to get this info without any security requirement. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I think AS3 is waaaaaaaay too high-level for this kind of stuff...

Comment: with ActionScript + AIR and access to some native functions this would be possible... otherwise I don't see how... what have you tried ? did you get eny error messages ?

Comment: @okami  I don't think you can get the hard drive serial number from a web browser.  The idea just sounds unholy from a feature perspective, and from an implementation perspective, none of the web technologies can access that data.

Comment: @okami what is the purpose of getting the serial number of the hdd.

Answer (score 5):

You could get all the physical media for a device from a C# console application and output each physical medium and its properties as an xml. Then in an Air application using the `NativeApplication` API you can get said physical medium and its properties, namely the serial number for a hard disk drive. I made an example of this:

GetPhysicalMedia.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Management;

namespace GetPhysicalMedia
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ManagementClass managementClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_PhysicalMedia");

            String physicalMediaXml = "";

            physicalMediaXml += "<physicalMedia>\n";

            foreach (ManagementObject managementObject in managementClass.GetInstances())
            {
                physicalMediaXml += "\t<physicalMedium ";
                physicalMediaXml += "caption" + "='" + managementObject["Caption"] + "' ";
                physicalMediaXml += "description" + "='" + managementObject["Description"] + "' ";
                physicalMediaXml += "installDate" + "='" + managementObject["InstallDate"] + "' ";
                physicalMediaXml += "name" + "='" + managementObject["Name"] + "' ";
                physicalMediaXml += "status" + "='" + managementObject["Status"] + "' ";
                physicalMediaXml += "creationClassName" + "='" + managementObject["CreationClassName"] + "' ";
                physicalMediaXml += "manufacturer" + "='" + managementObject["Manufacturer"] + "' ";
                physicalMediaXml += "model" + "='" + managementObject["Model"] + "' ";
                physicalMediaXml += "sku" + "='" + managementObject["SKU"] + "' ";
                physicalMediaXml += "serialNumber" + "='" + managementObject["SerialNumber"] + "' ";
                physicalMediaXml += "tag" + "='" + Regex.Replace((String)managementObject["Tag"], "\\\\", "&#92;") +"' ";
                physicalMediaXml += "version" + "='" + managementObject["Version"] + "' ";
                physicalMediaXml += "partNumber" + "='" + managementObject["PartNumber"] + "' ";
                physicalMediaXml += "otherIdentifyingInfo" + "='" + managementObject["OtherIdentifyingInfo"] + "' ";
                physicalMediaXml += "poweredOn" + "='" + managementObject["PoweredOn"] + "' ";
                physicalMediaXml += "removable" + "='" + managementObject["Removable"] + "' ";
                physicalMediaXml += "replaceable" + "='" + managementObject["Replaceable"] + "' ";
                physicalMediaXml += "hotSwappable" + "='" + managementObject["HotSwappable"] + "' ";
                physicalMediaXml += "capacity" + "='" + managementObject["Capacity"] + "' ";
                physicalMediaXml += "mediaType" + "='" + managementObject["MediaType"] + "' ";
                physicalMediaXml += "mediaDescription" + "='" + managementObject["MediaDescription"] + "' ";
                physicalMediaXml += "writeProtectOn" + "='" + managementObject["WriteProtectOn"] + "' ";
                physicalMediaXml += "cleanerMedia" + "='" + managementObject["CleanerMedia"] + "' ";
                physicalMediaXml += "/>\n";

            }// end foreach

            physicalMediaXml += "</physicalMedia>\n";

            Console.WriteLine(physicalMediaXml);

        }// end method

    }// end class

}// end namespace
```

Main.as:

```
package 
{
    import flash.desktop.NativeProcess;
    import flash.desktop.NativeProcessStartupInfo;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.filesystem.File;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var _nativeProcess:NativeProcess;
        private var _nativeProcessSUI:NativeProcessStartupInfo;
        private var _physicalMedia:XML;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            _nativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
            _nativeProcessSUI = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();

            _nativeProcessSUI.executable = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("GetPhysicalMedia.exe");
            _nativeProcess.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onNativeProcessSOD);
            _nativeProcess.addEventListener(Event.STANDARD_OUTPUT_CLOSE, onNativeProcessSOC);
            _nativeProcess.start(_nativeProcessSUI);

        }// end function

        private function onNativeProcessSOD(e:ProgressEvent):void
        {
            _physicalMedia = XML(_nativeProcess.standardOutput.readUTFBytes(_nativeProcess.standardOutput.bytesAvailable));

        }// end function

        private function onNativeProcessSOC(e:Event):void
        {
            trace(_physicalMedia.physicalMedium.(String(@tag).search("PHYSICALDRIVE0") > -1).@serialNumber); // output: V5FEVZ2W
            trace(_physicalMedia.physicalMedium.(String(@tag).search("PHYSICALDRIVE1") > -1).@serialNumber); // output: WD-WCASU2856512 

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

This is an example of the output you get for GetPhysicalMedia.exe:

```
<physicalMedia>
  <physicalMedium caption="" description="" installDate="" name="" status="" creationClassName="" manufacturer="" model="" sku="" serialNumber="V5FEVZ2W            " tag="\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0" version="" partNumber="" otherIdentifyingInfo="" poweredOn="" removable="" replaceable="" hotSwappable="" capacity="" mediaType="" mediaDescription="" writeProtectOn="" cleanerMedia=""/>
  <physicalMedium caption="" description="" installDate="" name="" status="" creationClassName="" manufacturer="" model="" sku="" serialNumber="WD-WCASU2856512     " tag="\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1" version="" partNumber="" otherIdentifyingInfo="" poweredOn="" removable="" replaceable="" hotSwappable="" capacity="" mediaType="" mediaDescription="" writeProtectOn="" cleanerMedia=""/>
  <physicalMedium caption="" description="" installDate="" name="" status="" creationClassName="" manufacturer="" model="" sku="" serialNumber="516256L411          " tag="\\.\CDROM0" version="" partNumber="" otherIdentifyingInfo="" poweredOn="" removable="" replaceable="" hotSwappable="" capacity="" mediaType="" mediaDescription="" writeProtectOn="" cleanerMedia=""/>
</physicalMedia>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that from FlashPlayer. You might ask for the user to type it manually the first time, use a `SharedObject` and never ask again.

With AIR you can fork native OS process and communicate it to obtain HDD serial number:

```
var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();  
var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("some_hdd_utility.exe");  
nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;  
var processArgs:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();  
processArgs.push("someArgs");  
nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = processArgs;  
process = new NativeProcess();  
process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onOutputData);  
process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);  
public function onOutputData(event:ProgressEvent):void  
{  
    var stdOut:ByteArray = process.standardOutput;  
    var data:String = stdOut.readUTFBytes(process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable);  
    trace("Got: ", data);  
}
```

Hope this helps.