# Reading mobile device hardware information from Flex mobile application?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

- How can I read the hardware information from Flex mobile application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Systems.Capabilities](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html) will give you some information. Not really sure exactly what information you are looking for though...

Comment: I am interesting in sort of unique serial numbers mostly, like Device ID.. etc.

Comment: @AlphaResearch Ah, I see. As far as I know, there is no way to do this directly with AS3. If you are using AIR you can use a Native Extension to get the info, provided the OS exposes it. For example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947143/how-to-get-hard-disk-serial-number-with-action-script but I have never done anything like this myself.